# In Razor, how do I show in image if the URL is already in a property of my model?

Tags: c#, image, url, razor, encoding

I have a class which has a property called `PictureURL`. It contains an absolute URL to the picture which should represent it as a string.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string PictureURL {get;set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to display it in a partial view.

```
@model MyClass
<div> 
    <img src="@Model.PictureUrl" />
    @Model.Name
</div>
```

The problem is that MVC encodes the property for the display. So my URL which contained an ampersand gets mangled. An example gravatar identicon would become `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0d958098841b2060bf685088b33e6662?d=identicon&amp;s=256`. Of course, the browser renders nothing with this broken img tag.

As far as I know, there is no HTML helper which builds `<img>` tags. And when I search for displaying images in Razor, the results I get are about properly resolving relative URLs.

What would be a good way to build the img tag properly? (I own the code of MyClass and can change its property type from string to something else, if this would help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Raw(Model.PictureUrl)` should solve this.

Comment: look at [this page](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/avoiding-cross-site-scripting-xss.html) to make sure you are careful and trust your data when using Html.Raw

Comment: @Jonesy thank you, very good point. In this case, all the links to images are entered by hand by the developers, I am not displaying user content here, so I feel secure about them. But of course, it is good to know it for the general case.